# Text area in HTML is showing code instead of being rendered and formatted

Tags: html, css

I have done textareas before but this one is just killing me. The text area is showing the html code and is not css'ed properly. So in the actual window I get the code for the textarea's element and it shows the rest of my code in it as well, instead of rendering it. Without the textarea tag everything works peachy.

```
<article>
<form method="POST" name="form9" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <label for="firstName">First Name <sup>*</sup></label>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" required />

    <label for="lastName">Last Name <sup>*</sup></label>
    <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName"/>

    <label for="wrstyle">Writing Style <sup>*</sup></label>
    <textarea placeholder="Please, briefly describe your writing style." type="text" id="wrstyle" name="wrstyle"</textarea>

    <label for="submit" class="centerit" title="Click here to register your account">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" />
                </label>
                <p class="notice"><sup>*</sup> denotes a required field.</p>

</form>
</article>
```

Comment: typo? The closing `>` is missing from textarea.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That did it. I am feeling silly and tired, thus blind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't close opening tag of the textarea (you are missing `>`):

http://jsfiddle.net/Bvk92/

It's also worth noting that [`<textarea>` has no `type` attribute.](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/textarea)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close tag of text area .......

```
 <article>
    <form method="POST" name="form9" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <label for="firstName">First Name <sup>*</sup></label>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" required />

        <label for="lastName">Last Name <sup>*</sup></label>
        <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName"/>

        <label for="wrstyle">Writing Style <sup>*</sup></label>
        <textarea placeholder="Please, briefly describe your writing style." type="text" id="wrstyle" name="wrstyle"></textarea>

        <label for="submit" class="centerit" title="Click here to register your account">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" />
                    </label>
                    <p class="notice"><sup>*</sup> denotes a required field.</p>

    </form>
    </article>
```